# Does `.rc` do anything in `after/plugin/foo.rc.vim`?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I see some people add a `.rc.` extention to files in `after/plugin`, is there any difference between:

- `after/plugin/foo.vim`
- `after/plugin/foo.rc.vim`
  ?

Or:

- `after/plugin/bar.lua`
- `after/plugin/bar.rc.lua`
  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no difference as long as file name matches `*.vim`

Well, actually, the scripts get sorted by names before being sourced, so it can somehow affect the order, but it shouldn't be the case here, I guess.